# Calling another powershell script with Get-Credentials - Odd result

Tags: powershell

Edited:

I have a powershell script that calls another script as elevated domain admin which returns an access denied error as follows:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At \\server\software$\!SystemSetup\PS_Scripts\LocalAdmin.ps1:16 char:5
+     $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Using this method to call the script produces the error:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $ScriptLocation" -Credential $Cred
```

However, If I just right click and run as administrator and enter my domain credentials to call the script (without using `$Cred`) works fine:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $ScriptLocation"
```

The script that I am calling looks like this:

```
$WindowsVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ForEach-Object -MemberName Caption

If ($WindowsVersion -match 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise') {

    $DomainName = "DOMAIN.COM"
    $ComputerName = (hostname)
    $Username = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName).Split('\')[1]
    $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
    $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
    $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)

    Write-Host "$Username added to Administrators" 

} Elseif ($WindowsVersion -match 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise' -or $WindowsVersion -match 'Microsoft Windows 7 Professional') {

    $DomainName = "DOMAIN.COM"
    $ComputerName = (hostname)
    $Username = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName).Split('\')[1]
    $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
    $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
    $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)

    Write-Host "$Username added to Administrators" 

} Else {

    Write-Host "Could not determine OS version"
}
```

I cannot figure out why storing my domain admin credentials in $Cred and passing it to the script gives me the access denied once it gets to `$AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)`

Comment: Does the admin have privileges to the file location?  *Run As Admin* is not the same as running it in a different user context.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 When I Run As Admin, I don't enter local admin credentials, I give it my Domain Admin, which is what I also have in $Cred. It is a file share that everyone has access to as long as they are in the Domain Users AD group, which they are. Everyone has read + execute there

Comment: Are you saying that your UAC is prompting you for credentials when you use *Run As Admin* then?  This is not the same as what your script is doing.  I also don't recall any elevation needed in order to access a fileshare.

Comment: Yes, UAC prompts me for credentials, I provide Domain Admin credentials, then run the above code to call the script from that elevated powershell instance, which works great.

I'm elevating the powershell instance because the script on the fileshare does things that require elevation.

Comment: I don't think you understand what @TheIncorrigible1 is explaining... "Run As Administrator" does not run powershell as a different account. The prompt is for an account that has the ability to elevate your (local) user account to have local-admin rights. Your scripts are different: one is running the command as the Domain Admin user, whilst the other 'Run As Administrator' is running the script as your user own account but with local-admin rights -- check this by looking at the Details tab in Task Manager to see what user account is being used.

Comment: I feel like I'm being misunderstood, I know what Run As Admin does. Run As Admin works, I am not having an issue with Run As Admin. I'm trying to figure out why the variant I am trying to use, does not work. 

I am passing my credentials to $Cred = Get-Credential and kicking off the script using $Creds produces access denied, on a script I own, on a share that I created, with rights that I currently have (that everyone has by default for that matter).

Also, after trying a couple more times, I realize I did not read the error correctly at all. I'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of TheIncorrigible1's comment, You can add this to your script at the beginning to check if it is running as admin. If it is not, it will relaunch as admin

```
If (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    $Arguments = "& '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "'"
    Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $Arguments
    Break
}
```

Then depending on your UAC setting you may be prompted to allow it to run with elevated privilege.

Comment: Does that check if its elevated as local or domain admin?